# Node.js Lighthouse custom Gatherer/Audit - Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Object reference chain is too long

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement custom audits using the lighthouse library [lighthouse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse) and executing some Javascript commands within the Gatherer I get the following error:

```
Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Object reference chain is too long
```

In detail I have the following Gatherer:

```
'use strict';
const { Gatherer } = require('lighthouse');

class customGatherer extends Gatherer {
 afterPass(options, loadData) {
    const expression = `window.document.getElementsByTagName('*')`;

    const driver = options.driver;

    return driver.evaluateAsync(expression);
 }
}

module.exports = customGatherer;
```

That with the `expression` defined above triggers the problem.
There seems to be too much information and I can't manage it. I'm testing the command on a web page and it returns 1059 collections (`HTMLCollection(1059)`).

When I run the lighthouse command to inspect a page, the warning is created and the result cannot be manipulated within the audit:

```
LH:Runner:warn customGatherer, required by audit my-custom-audit, encountered an error: Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Object reference chain is too long +0ms
```

NB: In the lighthouse log i can see also this error:

```
 LH:method <= browser ERR:error Runtime.evaluate  +24ms
```

I need to have a Gatherer that returns all HTMLCollection elements in order to compute them to get all the fonts on the page.
How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an artifact that collects all font information on a page: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/types/artifacts.d.ts#L139

As for the actual error, you'd need to write a more complex function that you'd pass to evaluate to process the DOM and return *only* the data you want. If you write anything more than a single-line expression I suggest using driver.evaluate instead (see the Lighthouse repo for examples).

Comment: thanks for the answer! Seems like what i need.
Just one thing: how can i pass a custom script to the Evaluate? I mean, if a write a complex Javascript function like: `const expression = 'function myfunc() {..} myfunc()'` it doesn't works and says like "missing ')' statement". 
So do you know how to pass more complex function to the Evaluate?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you should inspect the other gatherers in the lighthouse repository for examples on how to do just that. You won't pass a string but instead an actual reference to a function and it's parameters and dependency functions.

Comment: Oh, the function is called .evaluate, .evaluateAsync is the old version. I failed to mention that earlier, sorry!

Comment: Okay thanks that's clear! Reference and not a string function.
And do you know also what is the best practise in order to use an already existing Gatherer? Like if i would like to use the Artifact.Font[] gatherer how i should do that in the best way?